# Some of Windows 7 brightness sliders dissapeared

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, brightness

The sliders from Mobility Center and below the power plans list disappeared after some certain time/event, but Windows still can control the brightness of my laptop (VAIO VPCEB1J8E) through either by keyboard, or through the power plans.
Can you help me to restore this functionality?